# Mostrar dados e clicar neles para abrir

Tags: php

Tenho uma duvida.
Estou a fazer um trabalho onde tenho uma pagina que mostra o nome de um Clube.

```
 while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($qr)){

 echo '<p><h2>'.$exibe['Nome'].'</h2></p>';
 }
```

E quero que ao clicar o no nome ou num botão a frente me mostre a informação toda desse Clube noutra pagina.

```
 while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($qr)){

 echo'<div id="tabs-1">
 <img align="right" src="logos/'.$exibe["Nome"].'.jpg">
       <p>Nome:<b>'.$exibe["Nome"].'</b></p>
       <p>Morada:   '.$exibe["Morada"].'</p>
       <p>Distrito: '.$exibe["Distrito"].'</p>
       <p>Concelho: '.$exibe["Concelho"].'</p>
```

Comment: Apenas para eu entender o q você quer, algo como [**isso**](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible) seria suficiente?

Comment: Quero que ao clicar apareça os dados no segundo while. 
Por exemplo: Clico no nome "A" e quero que a seguir me mostre os dados que escolhi na segunda pagina

Answer (score 2):

Se você deseja redirecionar a informação clicando no nome deve criar um [hyperlink](/questions/tagged/hyperlink) para tal página passando alguma identificação. Vamos dizer que sua página que vai receber a informação após clicar no link chama-se `outrapagina.php` e queria buscar pelo `id` os dados, é só colocar assim `outrapagina.php?id=` e o seu código

```
while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($qr))
{
 echo '<p><h2><a href="outrapagina.php?id='.$exibe['id'].'">'.$exibe['Nome'].'</a></h2></p>';
}
```

Comment: Mas estou a ter um problema. Tenho dois dados com o esse que me indicou.
E ao clicar no primeiro mostra-me os dois . Quando so devia mostrar o primeiro

Comment: @user3253195, como você planejou sua tabela, ela tem um identificador de linha, um primary key?

Comment: meto where id=?

Comment: `outrapagina.php?id='.$exibe['id'].'` se você tiver o campo com o nome de id sim ou código ai vai depender da sua tabela, e na outra página você tem que resgatar esse id e utilizar na sql

Answer (score 2):

Você devera criar um redirecionamento para uma outra pagina e filtrar na sua base de dados com o id da pagina anterior.

```
while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($qr))
{
 echo '<p><h2><a href="outrapagina.php?id='.$exibe['id'].'">'.$exibe['Nome'].'</a></h2></p>';
}
```

isso você coloca na sua pagina principal, e na outrapagina.php, deverá resgatar o id passado pela pagina anterior

```
// resgata o id passado por url
$id = $_GET['id'];

//filtra os dados conforme o id;
$sql = mysql_query("select * from SUABASE where id = $id;");
$exibe = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

echo'<div id="tabs-1">
 <img align="right" src="logos/'.$exibe["Nome"].'.jpg">
       <p>Nome:<b>'.$exibe["Nome"].'</b></p>
       <p>Morada:   '.$exibe["Morada"].'</p>
       <p>Distrito: '.$exibe["Distrito"].'</p>
       <p>Concelho: '.$exibe["Concelho"].'</p>
```